# Endpoints configuration not updated

Tags: google-app-engine, backend, google-cloud-endpoints

Hello i am trying to deploy backends to google apps engine got error **java.lang.RuntimeException: Endpoints configuration not updated**,Front end deployed successfully but backends showing consistently loading,i didn't changed anything in code even also my eclipse,jdk & google sdk are same.Eclipse=indigo,jdk=1.7 & google sdk=1.8.5.
please let me know where i did mistakes.

Comment: Are you still having issues? If so it would be helpful if you file a bug on our [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) with more details.

Comment: Dear saiyr now we are converting our backends into modules.. i understood this issue...issue was appengine sdk version...But now i am facing problem related to modules....i created structure for that but even my front end not deploying on google apps do you know related module?

Comment: Please close this question and open a new one if you have a new issue. This is good stackoverflow etiquette.